Why doesn't my program professor.py pass check50? CS50 Python Problem Set 4 - Little Professor
I tried everything I could but I couldn't seem to find the issue. When I run my program normally, it gives me the correct output for everything. I cannot understand check50's error
Here are the specifications required: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/4/professor/
import random


def main():
    level = get_level()
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        problem = generate_integer(level)
        list = problem.split("=")
        prob = list[0]
        ans = list[1]
        ans = int(ans)
        answer = input(prob + "= ")
        if answer.isdigit():
            answer = int(answer)
        else:
            print("EEE")
            continue
        if answer != ans:
            print("EEE")
            answer1 = input(prob + "= ")
            answer1 = int(answer1)
            if answer1 == ans:
                score += 1
                continue
            if answer1 != ans:
                print("EEE")
                answer2 = int(input(prob + "= "))
                if answer2 == ans:
                    score += 1
                else:
                    print(prob + "= " + list[1])
                    continue
        else:
            score += 1
    print("Score:", score)


def get_level():
    while True:
        level = input("Level: ")
        if level.isdigit():
            level = int(level)
        else:
            continue
        if level != 1 and level != 2 and level != 3:
            continue
        else:
            break
    return level


def generate_integer(level):
    problem = ""
    if level == 1:
        X = random.randint(1, 9)
        Y = random.randint(1, 9)
    elif level == 2:
        X = random.randint(10, 99)
        Y = random.randint(10, 99)
    elif level == 3:
        X = random.randint(100, 999)
        Y = random.randint(100, 999)
    problem = f"{X} + {Y} = {X+Y}"
    return problem

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I saw other questions using random.seed(), but here I never used random.seed()



Questions related to CS50 might be appropriate for this site, however your question assumes the reader is either familiar with the problem or will take the time to follow your link.  Be aware, this site doesn't allow the posting of images code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Also, refrain from posting links to problem definitions and/or explanations Instead, incorporate the explanation into your question directly.

screenshot shows Could not find the following in the output "6 + 6 =" Actual found "Level 7 + 7=" - and maybe problem makes word Level. Maybe you should use input() instead of input("Level")

Yeah but, input("Level: ") is necessary for the program to work according to the specifications

This code
X = random.randint(1, 9)
Y = random.randint(1, 9)

does not "generate addition problems using 0-9"
